# Force google Maps to use a certain road

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have a question about Google Maps.

Is there a way to force google maps to use a certain road - I have KML files and if i enter  origin and destination, Google should display the route, that i gave in KML file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the DirectionsService in the api?

Comment: yes for an example waypoints, but I must give stop attribute manually

Comment: What does your code look like?  What does the KML look like?  How are you using the DirectionsService?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using waypoints in a DirectionsService request, then configure the request object with optimizeWaypoints:false. This will prevent Google trying to give you the best possible route, and will keep the order of waypoints that you pass in to the request

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the road into the directions.  For example Google maps always tries to force me to take I-25 home if I just put in two locations (work and home).  However if I add a third location and make it the road I want (work, E-470, home), it creates the route in such a way that the first stop is the road I want, then calculates the rest of the way home from there.  It works for me but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for this answer as well. The only way I found is doing it manually from the desktop by modifying the route by drag and drop on the map to correct the path. Once I'm satisfied with the result, share the link. The only problem is that you have limited changes allowed to the direction.

I hope there is a way to define a route for direction through API.

Answer (score -1):

Adding the highway as a destination in between worked for me.

As well, you can try to drag the blue route line to the highway you'd like. It didn't work every time but most times it understood what I was trying to do.